# IE11 F12 tools menu moved to top

Tags: remote-desktop, developer-tools

Until recently, the IE11 F12 Developer Tools window had a tab panel on the left to move between DOM Explorer, Console, Debugger etc. A few days ago I logged on to my computer from a remote machine through RDP, and when I opened F12, the left panel was replaced with a top tabs control. I thought it's because using RDP the Aero theme was disabled (it's a Windows 7 Enterprise), but the next time I logged on locally, the F12 window still looked the same. How do I restore it to the way it was, with icons on the left?

[image: F12 Developer Tools]
**Update**

IE version: 11.0.9600.17501

Update version: 11.0.15

Comment: You can still add a link to the picture

Comment: All the screen shots on the MS site are also showing it at the top... I wonder if this is due to an update? What version of IE11 do you have (full version, such as 11.0.9600.17107 and the update version)?

Comment: Having the same issue.   I am LOST in this new nav set up.  MS must've put it out in one of their forced updated that corporate pushed out.  Hate it.  Want the old one back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer i received on [TechNet forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/5dbf193c-70f6-48cc-bf7b-fbc4c750c198/ie11-f12-tools-menu-moved-to-top?forum=ieitprocurrentver):

It's redesigned. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/12/09/announcing-the-redesigned-f12-developer-tools-interface.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To move the F12 developer tool Windows in I.E from top  to its original position,

There is an shortcut keys to pin again the tool  to the internet Explorer

Ctrl + p.

Comment: This isn't what I asked. I asked about the tabs inside the Developer Tools window, not the docking of the window.